# Inserción en 4 tablas distintas en un formulario

Tags: php, mvc, insert

Soy algo nuevo en esto utilizo el modelo mvc para programar en PHP (novato en ese tipo de modelo) quisiera saber como hacer la inserción ya que mi formulario recaba campos de 4 tablas en mi base de datos y hasta ahora solo se insertan a una tabla y las demás las ignora les dejo el código de mi modelo.

```
public function getInsert($post){

   $fecha=$_POST['fecha']; 
   $responsable_velada=$_POST['responsable_velada'];
   $autorizo=$_POST['autorizo']; 
   $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
   $apellidop=$_POST['apellidop']; 
   $apellidom=$_POST['apellidom'];
   $area=$_POST['area'];  
   $clave=$_POST['clave']; 
   $descripcion=$_POST['decripcion'];
   $tipo_gasto=$_POST['tipo_gasto'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO velada (fecha, responsable_velada, autorizo)
              VALUES ('$fecha', '$responsable_velada', '$autorizo')";

     $sql = "INSERT INTO personal_velada (fecha, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, area)
            VALUES ('$fecha', '$nombre', '$apellidop', '$apellidom', '$area')";
     $sql = "INSERT INTO ordenes_trabajo (fecha, clave, descripcion,)
            VALUES ('$fecha', $clave, '$descripcion')";
     $sql = "INSERT INTO gastos_velada (fecha , tipo_gasto)
            VALUES ('$fecha', '$tipo_gasto')";

    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    if ( $query->execute()) {
       return true;
    }else{
       return false;
    }
}
```

> código de mi controlador

```
public function Guardar(){       
 $optionsmodel =$this->loadModel('OptionsModel');
 $insertar= $optionsmodel->getInsert($_POST);

  if ($insertar ) {
       echo "registro exitoso";
    }else 
       echo "error";
    {
  }                                                                                           
}
```

Comment: para una acción que implica la afectación de mas de una tabla es recomendable realizar una transacción. ya que esta podría fallar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás sólo ejecutando el último insert. Puedes por ejemplo usar diferentes nombres de variables:

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO velada (fecha, responsable_velada, autorizo)
          VALUES ('$fecha', '$responsable_velada', '$autorizo')";

 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO personal_velada (fecha, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, area)
        VALUES ('$fecha', '$nombre', '$apellidop', '$apellidom', '$area')";
 $sql3 = "INSERT INTO ordenes_trabajo (fecha, clave, descripcion,)
        VALUES ('$fecha', $clave, '$descripcion')";
 $sql4 = "INSERT INTO gastos_velada (fecha , tipo_gasto)
        VALUES ('$fecha', '$tipo_gasto')";

 $query1 = $this->db->prepare($sql1);
 $query2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
 $query3 = $this->db->prepare($sql3);
 $query4 = $this->db->prepare($sql4); 

 $query1->execute();
 $query2->execute();
 $query3->execute();
 $query4->execute();
```

Comment: muchas gracias tienes toda la razón

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo con una transacion, en caso de fallar este no te generara inconsistencia de datos.

```
 include_once "conexion.php";
        try {  

          $pdo->beginTransaction();

          $pdo->exec("insert into users (name, last_name, email, password) values ('Juan Leo', 'Juan leo/','juan@correo.com','123445')");
          $pdo->exec("insert into users (name, last_name, email, password) values ('Juan Leo', 'Juan leo/','juan@correo.com','123445')");
          $pdo->exec("insert into users (name, last_name, email, password) values ('Juan Leo', 'Juan leo/','juan@correo.com','123445')");



          $pdo->commit();// establece el autocomit en la bd, para realizar el guardado

        } catch (Exception $e) {
          $pdo->rollBack();// en caso de fallar rebierte los cambios afectados
          echo "Fallo: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```